# Why is raw string literal parsed before trailing backslash?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, string-literals, backslash, rawstring

From [Phases of translation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases), backslash joining next line happens in Phase 2 and string literal evaluation happens in Phase 3. Then why does the following code does string evaluation before?

```cpp
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

int main() {
    std::string s = R"(before\
after)";
    std::cout << s;
}
```

gives:

```
before\
after
```

instead of:

```
beforeafter
```

> Phase 2
>
> 1. Whenever backslash appears at the end of a line (immediately followed by zero or more whitespace characters other than new-line followed by (since C++23) the newline character), these characters are deleted, combining two physical source lines into one logical source line. [...]

> Phase 3
>
> 1. The source file is decomposed into comments, sequences of whitespace characters (space, horizontal tab, new-line, vertical tab, and form-feed), and preprocessing tokens, which are the following:
>    a) header names such as  or "myfile.h"
>    b) identifiers
>    c) preprocessing numbers
>    d) character and **string literals** , including user-defined (since C++11) [...]

Comment: string literal != raw string literal

Comment: "_...Any transformations performed during phases 1 and 2 between the initial and the final double quote of any raw string literal __are reverted__...."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raw string literals [*explicitly* undo phases 1&2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/lex.pptoken#3.1):

> If the next character begins a sequence of characters that could be the prefix and initial double quote of a raw string literal, such as R", the next preprocessing token shall be a raw string literal. Between the initial and final double quote characters of the raw string, any transformations performed in phases 1 and 2 (universal-character-names and line splicing) are reverted; this reversion shall apply before any d-char, r-char, or delimiting parenthesis is identified.

Comment: So the compiler goes back in time?  Cool!

Comment: @PaulSanders: The standard defines behavior; the implementation decides how to implement it. The standard is written as if the entire file were processed in each phase before moving on to the next, but implementations need not be written that way (and almost certainly are not).

Comment: I wasn't serious :)